# place local backup for app data in android 11 and higher using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, storage, backup

based on

[https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage](https://%20https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

I cannot create an app-specific directory

> Starting in Android 11, apps cannot create their own app-specific directory on external storage. To access the directory that the system provides for your app, call getExternalFilesDirs().

and I googled for a solution but couldn't find any clear article showing the right way to save files like backup data.

What I found are some native tries that do not fill the needs.

So anyone has any solution for that?